# JS extract text between brackets tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I searched and searched, but I just can't seem to find the correct answer, so I'm asking it here (regexp newbie).

I'm trying to extract the value **include this** between the following:

```
[tag1]include this [tag1]
```

I only want to get the value "include this" as an result. To make this more complex, the regex needs to look at the value **tag1**, because I got more than one of those brackets in the same body. To top it: the tekst on multiple lines has to be included.

So far, I tried the following single line regexp (can only use single line regexp):

```
(?!\[?.*\]).*(?=\{\/?.*\})
```

and

```
(\[[^\]]+\](?!\s)([\w']+)(?!\])\b|(?:^|\s)([\w']+)(?!\])\b)
```

These two both seem to do the trick for the first part (extract only the text "include this" between the tags, but he doesn't look at the part [tag1]. So in short: i'm looking for a regexp which can extract the value "include this" while looking at the inside of the brackets, the "tag1".

I'm feeling real close, but now i'm stuck.

Please help?

Comment: Are you sure that the closing tag is `[tag1]` not `[/tag1]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "look at the value tag1"?

Comment: @sємsєм, your right the closing tag should be [/tag1]

Comment: @mtanti, the regexp must look what is inside the brackets (in my example tag1) and then capture what is between the tags [tag1] and [/tag1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[tag1\]((?:(?!\[tag1\]).)+)
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the capture.

http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/117

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Do you know how to adjust the Regexp to  capture multiple lines?

Comment: @mast use s flag or DOTALL OR \s\S if u don't have flags

Answer (score 1):

This will match two matching tags and extract the middle.

`\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[\1\]`

$1 backreference will get your tag ("tag1" in your example), and $2 will pull out the inner text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all text between two "tag1" tags do this

```
(?<=\[tag1\])(.|\r|\n)*?(?=\[/?tag1\])
```

If you want all text between matching tags do this

```
(?<=\[([a-z0-9]+)\])(.|\r|\n)*?(?=\[/?\2\])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may able to do it without Regex by creating a function takes the tag and the string as parameters, like the following:

```
function extractText(tag, str){    
        tL = tag.length; //tag length
        tP = str.indexOf(tag); // position of tag
        sT = str.substr((tP+tL)); //remaining string after tag          
        cT = sT.indexOf(tag); //closing tag position
        return sT.substring(0,cT)
}


<a href="javascript:alert(extractText('[tag1]','[tag1] include this [tag1]'))">Test</a>
```

A live demo is [here](http://jsbin.com/yujejerosa/1/)

Comment: From the OP (you're just missing a loop): `"I got more than one of those brackets in the same body"`

Comment: Namely I followed the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Or don't use regexp, which is what I usually do when the regexp "won't behave"[1] and what you're doing is pretty straight forward.  (I realize your question explicitly asked for regexp, but hopefully this is potentially helpful.)

```
function parseTags(str)
{
    var indexNext,
        arrayOut = [];

    while (str.indexOf("[tag1]") >= 0)
    {
        str = str.substring(str.indexOf("[tag1]") + 6);

        // What do you want to do if a tag's missing?
        // Skipping the end tag-less "match" for now.
        indexNext = str.indexOf("[tag1]");
        if (indexNext >= 0)
        {
            arrayOut.push(str.substring(0, indexNext));
            str = str.substring(indexNext + 6);
        }
        // Alternately, could `break` on else and save a trip.
    }

    return arrayOut;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z432hg0u/1/).

[1] Yes, I realize that's *my* failure when the regexp "won't behave".  ;^)